# distribution functions or not

Tags: probability, probability-theory

If $F(x)$ is a distribution function of a random variable .

If $G_1(x)=(F(x))^3$ and

$G_2(x)=1-(1-F(x))^5$

which of them is a $d.f$ .
My answer is that both of them are $d.f$ because they both are $1$ at $\infty$
 and $0$ at $-\infty$ 
They are right continuous as well 
And to use the non negativity of$ f(x) $  we see that both are non decreasing.Is it correct?

Comment: Do they both satisfy the requirements for a (cumulative) distribution function? You should make sure of this.

Comment: i have added this in the question now

Comment: So you are claiming that any function which is $1$ at $\infty$ and $0$ at $-\infty$ is a distribution function? That's not correct... there are other properties which you have to check.

Comment: right continuous as well

Comment: also should be non decreasing

Comment: Cant somebody atleast hint something correct if i am wrong any counterexample

Comment: In general yes you are checking the those conditions. Here is another check for this particular problem: Let $X_i$ be i.i.d. random variables with the common CDF $F$. What is the CDF of $\max\{X_1, X_2, X_3\}$ and $\min\{X_1, X_2, X_3, X_4, X_5\}$?

Comment: Yes the first case gives me  $G_1$ and second gives me $G_2$. it uses independence